# Dimension Door and Spell Combat

Tags: pathfinder-1e, spells, magus

So, to start, I'm aware of the feat [Dimensional Agility](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/general-feats/dimensional-agility/), but that doesn't seem exactly right with how it works with Spell Combat. Dimensional Agility makes Dimension Door basically not count as your move action, as well as your standard. But, if it's used in sync with the [Magus's Spell Combat class feature](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/base-classes/magus/#TOC-Spell-Combat-Ex-) which states:

> A magus can choose to cast the spell first or make the weapon attacks first, but if he has more than one attack, he cannot cast the spell between weapon attacks.

... and the only restriction on Spell Combat is:

> ...can also cast any spell from the magus spell list with a casting time of 1 standard action (any attack roll made as part of this spell also takes this penalty).

While the [Dimension Door spell itself](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/d/dimension-door) is, indeed, a standard action, but the spell forces you to not take any *other* actions afterwards. But what if it's used first or second as a part of Spell Combat, as a *part* of a full attack?

Because it's part of a full-round action (full attack), there wouldn't technically *be* any "other actions" besides the full attack. I guess this question boils down to "What is a full-round action, and is it made up of other actions?".

Say a Magus starts 50 feet from the enemy. He uses Spell Combat as a full-attack to use Dimension Door behind the enemy and get all of his attacks. Would this be legal according to RAW, or would the spell description overwrite it?

In either case, I believe there would be nothing stopping you from casting Dimension Door at the end of your attacks to teleport away from any threatening enemies, except a failed Concentration check.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Yes, a Magus can use Dimension Door as part of Spell Combat

A full-round action is one of several different actions, but none of them are specifically broken up into standard-move action pairs, so there is no reason why Dimension Door's action restriction should apply beginning in the middle of any full-round action.

As in your question the magus would be able to begin the full-round action, cast the spell, attack, then end the full-round action without taking any "other actions" after casting the spell.

Answer (score 1):

One thing to always remember is *specific beats general.*

[Dimension Door](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/d/dimension-door) states that no actions may be taken after it is cast.

[Dimensional Agility](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/general-feats/dimensional-agility/) states "...you can take any actions you still have remaining on your turn [after casting Dimension Door]."

[Spell Combat](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/base-classes/magus/#TOC-Spell-Combat-Ex-) is actually it's *own* action, a full-round action, that would *include* a melee attack *and* casting Dimension Door.

With these things in mind, there is actually no contradiction to worry about. You need Dimensional Agility only if you are not using Spell Combat. There are only two situations to ponder:

1) You cast Dimension Door normally, or

2) You cast Dimension Door as a part of Spell Combat.

Either way, you finish your turn as Spell Combat is a full-round, or because Dimension Door disallows any following actions.

Comment: This answer isn't incorrect, why the downvotes?

Answer (score 0):

I believe the problem here is actually with how you have understood Dimension Door, and it's interaction with Dimensional Agility.

[Dimension Door](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/d/dimension-door) is not just taking away your move action, it is also preventing you from taking ANY action until your next turn - no free actions, no swift actions, no immediate actions. You could not, for instance, cast Feather Fall or take an Attack of Opportunity after using Dimension Door, or even speak. Even when using Spell Combat to cast Dimension Door, this still all applies, so there are still consequences for using Dimension Door at the end of a Spell Combat routine.

[Dimensional Agility](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/general-feats/dimensional-agility/) does not give all of that back to you, but it does allow you to take other actions on your own turn once you arrive. This would allow you to take Free or Swift actions, for instance, after using Spell Combat. You would still, generally, be unable to move more than a 5-foot step, although the feat would allow the use of something like a [Quick Runner's Shirt](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic-items/wondrous-items/wondrous-items/r-z/shirt-quick-runners/).